# Matplotlib created a temporary config/cache directory

Tags: python-3.x, django, matplotlib, django-wsgi

Matplotlib created a temporary config/cache directory at /var/www/.config/matplotlib because the default path (/tmp/matplotlib-b33qbx_v) is not a writable directory; it is highly recommended to set the MPLCONFIGDIR environment variable to a writable directory, in particular to speed up the import of Matplotlib and to better support multiprocessing.

This is the message I'm getting in error.log file and 504 Gateway Time out error on browser .
Someone please help to resolve this issue.

Answer (score 7):

Please check:
https://github.com/pyinstaller/pyinstaller/issues/617

I run matplotlib from the webserver and use:
os.environ['MPLCONFIGDIR'] = '/opt/myapplication/.config/matplotlib'
This dir should writable by the web server (e.g. www-data).

Answer (score 6):

import os
os.environ['MPLCONFIGDIR'] = os.getcwd() + "/configs/"

before

import matplotlib

works for me

Comment: it works for me but make them in two lines

import os
os.environ['MPLCONFIGDIR'] = os.getcwd() + "/configs/"